# Ninject: Can modules be loaded that are declared as internal

Tags: ninject

Is it at all possible to configure Ninject to load modules that have been declared as `internal`?

I have tried configuring `InternalVisibleTo` for the Ninject assembly, but this does not help.

I can of course make the modules `public`, but really they should be `internal`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internally `KernalBase.Load(IEnumerable<Assembly assemblies)` uses the `GetExportedTypes()` which only returns public types.

However, you could write your own "NinjectModule scanner".

```cs
public static class NinjectModuleScanner
{
    public static IEnumerable<INinjectModule> 
        GetNinjectModules(IEnumerable<Assembly assemblies)
    {
        return assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetNinjectModules());
    }
}

public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<INinjectModule> 
        GetNinjectModules(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(IsLoadableModule)
            .Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type) as INinjectModule);
    }

    private static bool IsLoadableModule(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(INinjectModule).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            && !type.IsAbstract
            && !type.IsInterface
            && type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
    }
}
```

Then you could do the following.

```cs
var modules = NinjectModuleScanner.GetNinjectModules(assemblies).ToArray();
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

This solution has not been tested though.

Comment: Works very well, hadn't thought of approaching it like that as I was looking for something built in. Thanks.

Comment: just the idea of DI is horrible and grotesque, this make it worse to another whole level.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure Ninject to inject internal classes using the `InjectNonPublic` property from [`NinjectSettings`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Ninject/Ninject/NinjectSettings) class. You have to pass it as an argument to the [`StandardKernel`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Ninject/Ninject/StandardKernel/ctor) constructor:

```cs
var settings = new NinjectSettings
{
    InjectNonPublic = true
};
kernel = new StandardKernel(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

var modules = Assembly
                    .GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .DefinedTypes
                    .Where(typeof(INinjectModule).IsAssignableFrom)
                    .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                    .Cast<INinjectModule>();

kernel.Load(modules);
```