# AOP interceptor on private methods

Tags: c#, autofac, interceptor, intercept

how do i intercept the private method? Currently i'm using Autofac dynamicproxy2 but it only support public method..  I'm open to any other provider (e.g. MEF, Unity, ninject) to support private method interception.  any suggestions please?

Comment: Why are you trying to intercept a private method?

Comment: what i need to achieve is to log all methods... I need to intercept the start time and end time of every single methods.

Comment: Private methods should be helpers and probably do not need logged. That is more of a general rule, though...so I would mark your calls internal, which many frameworks can handle.

Comment: ok.. how do i do that..  i cannot find any AOP framework to support non-public methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454860/ninject-can-modules-be-loaded-that-are-declared-as-internal

Comment: PostSharp supports these kinds of things, but to be honest, if you need this, there is a problem with your design. Throwing tools at it won't fix the problems with your design and while it might make this particular pain go away, the design problems will keep haunting you.

Comment: i know postsharp does it.. but i don't have the budget to purchase the licensee...  anyway i'm doing this for debug/development purposes only and NOT to be deployed to production.   During the development, I need the ability to log how long each methods (public, private, protected, internal, everything) take time to execute.

Comment: [NConcern .NET](https://github.com/Virtuoze/NConcern) support private methods and is an open source project.
It is available as [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NConcern/) if you want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

NConcern.NET is a very good option but sadly it does not seem to support methods with generic types on the signature.